# Recurrence Relation for Longest Increasing Subsequence Problem

Tags: dynamic-programming, recurrence-relation, longest-increasing-subsequence

I am trying to solve the Longest Increasing Subsequence(LIS) Problem using different OPT Function than the one which normally used. I have been given this question as an extra credit and I have been trying to wrap my head around the different OPT Functions and the recurrence relation possible. The solutions I found always have some flaw in it. I will share the solutions I got below.

**Here is the  main question:**

Given a sequence of numbers stored in an array A[1 . . . n] = ⟨a<sub>1</sub>, . . . , a<sub>n</sub>⟩,
compute a subsequence of A of maximum length (i.e., number of
elements) whose elements are increasing

**Our Usual Approach to LIS Problem is:**

Let OPT(i) denote the length of the longest increasing subsequence of A that ends with a<sub>i</sub>.

Before the ending element, there is an element immediately before the ending element, i.e., the second to last element.

let a<sub>j</sub> be an element immediately before a<sub>i</sub> for an increasing subsequence, i.e., the subsequence ends with a<sub>j</sub>, a<sub>i</sub>

Recursive definition of OPT(i) will be:

```
OPT(i) = 1, if i = 1

OPT(i) = max {{1} ∪ {1 + OPT(j) | 1 ≤ j < i ∧ aj < ai}} otherwise
```

The answer to the input is: max{OPT(i) | 1 ≤ i ≤ n}

**The new Approach that I have to take to solve this problem for Extra Credit:**

A more ‘natural’ definition of OPT would be:

Let OPT(i) denote the length of the longest increasing subsequence within ⟨a<sub>1</sub>, . . . , a<sub>i</sub>⟩

So for an Input Array A = [4, 5, 6, 1, 2] the OPT Array should be = [1,2,3,3,3].

I have tried using the following recurrence relations for OPT(i) to solving this problem:

***1) First Attempt***

```
OPT (1) = 1

For i > 1, let LIS_i be the set of all j where 1 ≤ j < i and aj < ai

If LIS_i is empty, then OPT(i) = 1.

Otherwise, OPT(i) = 1 + max{OPT (j) | for all j € LIS_i}
```

Feedback: Based on the recursive definition, OPT[4]=1 because no elements before 1 is smaller than 1. OPT[4] should be 3 because the longest increasing subsequence of <4, 5, 6, 1> is 4 5 6.

***2) Second Attempt***

```
OPT(i) = max{OPT(j) + 1 | 1 ≤ j < i ∧ aj < ai, OPT(i-1)}
```

Feedback: The OPT Array this recurrence relation generates is = [1,2,3,3,4].

I solved the previous problem of OPT[4] giving 1 by comparing the OPT value by previous element. But now there is a new problem I am facing.

I am getting the value for OPT[5] = 4 , which is wrong as there does not exist any LIS of length 4 in the given array.

This is because it is computing max{OPT[4]+1,OPT[4]}. When i = 5, and j=4 it considers that the LIS ends with 1(a<sub>j</sub>), which it incorrect.

OPT[4] gets its value to be 3 because A[4] which is 1 is not part of the LIS but the element before it (OPT[3]) has a larger OPT value which is 3. So it simply copies the largest value.

*What I think is the correct approach is:*

Our OPT(i) is the length of the longest increasing subsequence within ⟨a<sub>1</sub>, . . . , a<sub>i</sub>⟩. This does not necessarily mean that the LIS should be ⟨a<sub>1</sub>, . . . , a<sub>i</sub>⟩. It is within ⟨a<sub>1</sub>, . . . , a<sub>i</sub>⟩, so it could be ⟨a<sub>1</sub>, . . . , a<sub>i-1</sub>⟩, ⟨a1, . . . , a<sub>i-2</sub>⟩, so on.

I really need help solving this problem. Your feedback help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should look up the $O(n \log (n))$ algorithm for LIS. You will realize that it uses $L[i][k] = $ increasing subsequence of $\langle a_1,...,a_i \rangle$ with length $k$ with the smallest possible last element and some placeholder if no such seq. exists . Using this your def. of OPT(i) becomes easy. Now you just need to find a recursion for $L$.